# Exchange / Office 365: set attendee not to cancel recurring events if conflicts occur

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I need to configure a booking attendee for ressource mailboxes. The problem now is the following:

I create a recurring event to appear every weekday at 1 P.M. and there are already two appointments on Tuesday and Friday at that specific time. What the attendee does now is declining the whole recurring event!

I would like the attendee to only decline the time slots on days that conflict with existing meetings (e.g. TU & FR) and book the reminding days (e.g. MO, WE & TH). Is there a way to do that properly?